# Making AST using antlr3 in reverse order

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm learning antlr3 and for it I'm modifying a Javascript grammar (I got the grammar from [here](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g)) to add supporting for AST generation.
Now, I'm trying to add AST support for "function calls" using multiples arguments (For instance: `aFunction(1)(2)(3)(4)`).
In my model, the previous example must create an AST like:

```
                                 CALLEXPRESSION
                      CALLEXPRESSION        Arguments(4)
              CALLEXPRESSION        Arguments(3)
     CALLEXPRESSION     Arguments(2)
undef           Arguments(1)
```

At the moment, I have a the following rules to handle this situation:

```
callExpression
: f=memberExpression! (LT* callExpressionSuffix[$f.tree]^)
;

callExpressionSuffix[param]
: arguments oCallSuf=callExpressionSuffix[param] -> ^(CallExpression $oCallSuf arguments)
| (->{param})
;
```

but these are creating an AST like:

```
                                   CALLEXPRESSION
                        CALLEXPRESSION      Arguments(1)
              CALLEXPRESSION        Arguments(2)
     CALLEXPRESSION     Arguments(3)
undef           Arguments(4)
```

(with the arguments in reverse order)

The question is:
How can I reverse the order of the arguments using pure "antlr3 language"?

Comment: Since you're starting with ANTLR, why are you stating with an old major version?

Comment: Hi Lucas, It's cos I'm working with a ecmaScript grammar developed for run under antlr3. Also, the idea is generate the AST, reading a little bit about antlr4 I found that it generate the parse tree.

Comment: There's an [ECMAScript grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ecmascript) for ANTLR4 too. And don't worry about the AST, ANTLR4 forces you to write your own CST->AST conversion step (if you want an AST), but this is an opportunity to fine-tune the AST the way you want it to be.